# How can a PlantUML document specify its diagram type?

Tags: plantuml

As far as I can tell, PlantUML auto-detects the diagram type for a given document (sequence diagram, usecase diagram, class diagram, activity diagram, etc.).  This seems to work reasonably well, but I sometimes find that while editing a diagram I will make some seemingly minor change and suddenly my Activity diagram becomes a Class diagram (for example).

I would like some way to tell PlantUML what the diagram type is, and have compilation fail if the syntax isn't valid for that one chosen diagram type, but I haven't been able to find anything like this in the PlantUML documentation.  Does such a diagram type identifier exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to start the diagram description with something that is specific to only one type of diagram.

E.g. if I had just the following line

```
A --> B
```

- For a class diagram, I could add `class A` before it
- For an activity diagram, I could change it to `A -->[ ] B`
- For a sequence diagram, I could add `participant A` before it

etc.

In none of the cases is the visualization changed – I'm only adding what would be added automatically anyway.

Comment: Why is this still making a class diagram then? ```@startuml
"User" -up-> "Tenant"
"Application" -up-> "Tenant"
"Group" -up-> "Tenant"
"Role" -up-> "Application"
"User" -up-> "Group"
"Registration" -up-> "User"
"Registration" -up-> "Application"
"User" -up-> "Role"
"Entity" -up-> "Application"
@enduml
```