# PlantUML: How to change diagram style

Tags: plantuml

for a while I'm using PlantUML to create sequence diagram.
Everything works fine ... but looked a bit boring and "geek"-like.

So I google for nice sprites and found [PlantUML Icon-Font Sprites](https://github.com/tupadr3/plantuml-icon-font-sprites#plantuml-icon-font-sprites) on GitHub.
I included the sprites successfully in my sequence diagram but as soon as I used them, I got a syntax error.
After some investigation, I discovered that PlantUML tries to create state diagrams and certain elements of the sequence diagram (like the separator) are not valid.

So my two questions:

1. How does PlantUML decide which diagram type to draw?
2. How can I change this to sequence diagrams?

**Example**

```
@startuml
!pragma teoz true
skinparam defaultTextAlignment center

!include puml-icons/common.puml
!include  puml-icons/font-awesome-5/user.puml

hide footbox
/'FA5_USER(Alice, Alice)
FA5_USER(Bob, Bob)'/

Alice -> Bob: Authentication Request
Bob --> Alice: Authentication Response
@enduml
```

[image: Sequence diagram]

```
@startuml
!pragma teoz true
skinparam defaultTextAlignment center

!include puml-icons/common.puml
!include  puml-icons/font-awesome-5/user.puml

hide footbox
FA5_USER(Alice, Alice)
FA5_USER(Bob, Bob)

Alice -> Bob: Authentication Request
Bob --> Alice: Authentication Response
@enduml
```

[image]

Comment: In the last comment of the issue: https://github.com/tupadr3/plantuml-icon-font-sprites/issues/2 I read "This is now included in V1.2017.19", did you try the direct from plantuml? I tried the example they gave themselves but this doesn't work ( :-( )

Comment: Hi @albert, Well, the example works for me ... but it's not what the question was because also the new syntax create the same diagram style and not a sequence diagram as I intend to.

Comment: It was just a wild guess from my side and I see that the discussion is already going on at https://forum.plantuml.net/10244/selecting-the-diagram-style. FWIW with the mentioned github issue a new example has been posted.

Answer (score 0):

See [How can a PlantUML document specify its diagram type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33092538/how-can-a-plantuml-document-specify-its-diagram-type)

And Examples on https://plantuml.com/commons that gives an idea how PlantUML decides what diagram to generate.

You can use hidden elements of specific type, like `component` for deployment diagram, to point PlantUML into right direct, when there is mix.